# Removing even numbers from queue

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, queue, nodes

I got stuck when trying to remove even number from queue in C programming. Here is the code:

```
void deleteEven(Queue *que)
{
    while (!isEmptyQueue(que)) {
        if ((que->list.first->data) % 2 == 0) {
            dequeue(que->list.first->data);
        }
    }
}

int dequeue(Queue *que)
{
    int x;
    if (que->list.first!= NULL) {
        x= ((que->list).first)->data;
        remove(&que->list, 0);
        que->list.size--;
        return x;
    }
    else return NULL;
}
```

What I am trying to do is first, I tried to check if the queue is empty. Then I will get the linked list head and modulus with 2, if getting 0 means it's even number and then I will dequeue it from the queue.

However, with these code, when I try to dequeue even numbers from queue, it just stopped working and not showing any error message.

Anybody know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if you have any odd elements in the list, your queue will never become empty when you remove only even elements. Which means it is a bad termination condition.

Comment: I see I see. Any alternate ways to fix this?

Comment: @MOehm Do you have any ideas why the edited portion still crashes?

Comment: The memory you allocated to `odd` is uninitialised. You should start with a zero size and a null head pointer.

Comment: So what am I supposed to modify now? I am really confused. Can you post some code example? The two guys who deleted their answer previously told me to use the malloc but I not sure if I am using at the correct place

Comment: @MOehm Any ideas? I am still stuck, I have been doing this for hours :(

Comment: What is the crashed message? First I noticed that free(odd->list.first->data)   is something wrong because we use free() on a pointer that has been allocated. What you did is freeing an integer. Secondly, I don't see any necessary to modify the odd queue after enqueue every node in it back to the original queue. I will recommend free it. Actually you don't need to allocate any memory to odd because it won't be used other where in the code.

Comment: It has no error message but when I tried to print it out, it just showing nothing and when I close the cmd, I saw ^C was printed out.

Comment: I'll first recommend you initializing the list in odd queue. Just do odd->list.size = 0 and odd->list.first = NULL. Then, when you try to enqueue those in the odd queue back to the original queue, do enqueue first and then simply do dequeue on odd. Don't go directly into queue's list.

Comment: @ChuanzhenWu Would you mind to provide me with some code example?

Comment: By the way, the dequeue you used on the original queue is also not correct. You should pass the que as parameter not que->list.first->data which is an integer.

Comment: Alright sure. But for the first part where you mentioned enqueue every node in it back to the original queue, would you mind to provide me with some code examples?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93867/discussion-between-chuanzhen-wu-and-i-was-so-lost).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edited edition and my imagination of the remove() function and the enqueue() function, I think what you really need is like following.

```
void deleteEven(Queue *que)
{
    Queue *odd =(Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    odd->list.size = 0;
    odd->list.first = NULL;
    while (!isEmptyQueue(que)) {
        if ((que->list.first->data) % 2 != 0) {
            enqueue(odd, que->list.first->data);
        }
        //dequeue(que->list.first->data); wrong
        dequeue(que); // passing the queue to dequeue function, not an integer
    }
    while (!isEmptyQueue(odd)) {
        enqueue(que, odd->list.first->data);
        dequeue(odd); // simply do dequeue on odd
    }
    free(odd);
}
```

Because there is not any error message or crash happen, I assume the bug is caused by the your misuse of dequeue function which didn't dequeue at all.

Comment: It told me unintialized odd variable used. So I initialize it to NULL?

Answer (score 0):

```
void deleteEven(Queue *que)
{
    Queue newq;

    newq.List.first = NULL;
    newq.List.size = 0;

    while (!isEmptyQueue(que)) 
    {
        if ((que->list.first->data) % 2 != 0) 
        {
            enqueue(newq, que->list.first->data);
        }
        dequeue(que);
    }

    while (!isEmptyQueue(newq)) 
    {
        enqueue(que, dequeue(newq));
    }
}
```

Comment: @IWasSoLost, read your chat discussion with Chuanzhen Wu and got the answer. Good Luck :)